# Output division result including digits after decimal - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am sorry if it's already answered in here, but I couldn't find the exact solution I am looking for.

I am trying to output  the result of a division of two variable which is continuously changing. The result may vary from 0.00 to 100.12314235234523 (not exactly this specific, I just wanted to give you an idea). I want to print the result only 2 digits after the decimal point, if there is nothing after decimal, it should print 2 zeroes after decimal.

For example:

10 / 5 = 2.00

23 / 6 = 3.83

I don't need to round up the result for example, if the output is: 73.4869999, I don't need it to be 73.49, 73.48 is fine with me.

What I have written so far is:

```
packet_loss[2]->setText(QString("%1%2%3").arg(((data.packet_loss_tx) * 100) / data.packets_tx).
                                          arg(locale.decimalPoint()).
                                          arg((((data.packet_loss_tx) * 100) % data.packets_tx), 2, 10, QChar('0')));
```

But this prints all the values after the decimal point. I can divide this part `arg((((data.packet_loss_tx) * 100) % data.packets_tx)` with 10, 100 or 1000 to reduce the number of decimals after the decimal point but this is a variable which changes every seconds. So if the output is 3 digits after decimal and I divide it by 10, I will get proper output, but the next value may be 5 digits after decimal and division by 10 will give me 4 digits after decimal. I want the final output to show only 2 digits after decimal.

Comment: `QString::number(100.12914235234523, 'f', 2)` will give you "100.13".

Comment: @vahancho, If I write the code like this: `QString::number(((data.packet_loss_tx) * 100) / data.packets_tx), 'f', 2)`, it gives me only `xxx.00`. It doesn't give me the actual digits after decimal.

Comment: Isn't it because you multiply it by integer value (100)? Try to use 100.0 instead.

Comment: @vahancho, Thanks. That solved it. It was a stupid question. Could you please add the comment as an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `QString::number()` function with specific formatting options (two digits precision). For example:

```
auto s = QString::number(100.12914235234523, 'f', 2); // Gives "100.13"
```

Besides, if you use floating point numbers, it's better to multiply them with floating point numbers too. I.e. you need to perform your calculations using 100.0 instead of integer value 100.